# Using find to copy over contents

Tags: unix

I am trying to copy over the contents from a file to a directory.
I wrote the command `find . -name "file" | while read f; do cp "$$f" directory; done`

This however moves the actual filename with the contents. I only want the contents of "file" to get placed into the directory appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I cannot understand the difference, could you give an example? Are those files already in the new directory? In such case you would like to say `cat "$f" >> ...` to append data in them.

Comment: Appending may work if it was redirected into another file I receive error messages  when trying to append to a directory. The desire outcome for me is "directory -> contents" as of now I am getting "directory -> file -> contents".